# vscode-remote-container open user terminal after post*Command

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, terminal, containers

if you run a `post*Command` you get an integrated terminal that runs the command(s) and outputs:

> Running the PostCreateCommand from devcontainer.json...
>
> [2709 ms] Start: Run in container: ...
>
> Done. Press any key to close the terminal.

is there a way to have this auto close and open a user terminal or just leave it and open a user terminal as if you werent running any commands from `devcontainer.json` at all?

Comment: Did you find an answer to that? I am stuck on it for several days...

Answer (score 2):

Using an example involving Python, you can try using `postAttachCommand`:

```json
{
    "postCreateCommand": ["poetry", "install"],
    "postAttachCommand": "bash"
}
```

which gives:

```
Running the postCreateCommand from devcontainer.json...

[28000 ms] Start: Run in container: poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update

Installing the current project: project (0.1.0)

Running the postAttachCommand from devcontainer.json...

[33815 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c bash
root@a0fd27a3b2cc:/workspaces/directory#
```

The description for `postCreateCommand` reads:

> A command to run after creating the container. This command is run after "updateContentCommand" and **before "postStartCommand"**.

whereas the description for `postAttachCommand` specifies:

> A command to run when attaching to the container. This command is run **after "postStartCommand".**

So other variations might be possible, but this one worked for me.

Comment: ya but is it possible to get it to run the background?

Comment: also, when you do this, vscode thinks its still configuring the container and shows the spinner in the status bar at the bottom.